# All codes are gone from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday, I changed my project's package name and today when I open the project I saw that there is nothing. Whole files in src folder are gone but files in res are not.
How can I recover codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at VCS -> Local History -> Show History.
If you have history that delete all files in src you can revert to before deletion